# TextInputLayout not showing error message after clearing

Tags: android, user-interface, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout from com.android.support:design:23.3.0

When I first apply an error it is shown correctly.

```
mInputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
mInputEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
```

[image]

On the next login attempt I clear the error.

```
mInputEmail.setError(null);
mInputPassword.setError(null);
```

Then I run the validation and set the error again using the same code as above but this time the red line is applied but the error text is missing.
[image]

Anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening or have experienced similar situations?

I saw something similar reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190355) but it is for an older version of the design library and don't know if it is still a issue in the verison I am using,

Comment: have you tried to set `setErrorEnabled(true)` right before setting the error the second time? I know this should not be a acceptable behaviour of an Object, but maybe at some point it falls back to `false`.....

Comment: otherwise, please show your gradle file....

Comment: I tried setting the error enabled to true before setting the error a second time and it had no effect.

Comment: have you done the step setErrorEnabled(false) after setError(null) ? Try this and then setErrorEnabled(true) befor the next setError("error");....

Comment: setting setErrorEnabled(false) straight after setError(null) seems to have fixed the problem. If you would like to write this up as an answer I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: glad that it works..... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply has to do these steps:

```
setErrorEnabled(true);
setError("error");
```

for clearing:

```
setError(null);
setErrorEnabled(false);
```

repeat the first step to set a new error. `setError(null)` clears the error message and icon, so I think the view to show is simply gone and `setErrorEnabled(false)` will reset it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this issue. I think the setErrorEnabled(true) may be unnecessary as this is called inside of setError("yourString")

Comment: Note: if you set `app:errorEnabled="true"` in your TextInputLayout in xml, it would inflate the space for error and there might be no need in using `setErrorEnabled()` programmatically.