# Text input layout throws error on setError method

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am applying the `setError()` method on `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` but I am getting this error,

What I am trying to achieve is the error tooltip.I am in no mood of using any third party libraries to achieve this.\

Here is what I tried and none of these worked,

[Error in TextInputLayout dont show again even call setErrorEnabled(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570339/error-in-textinputlayout-dont-show-again-even-call-seterrorenabledtrue)

[TextInputLayout setErrorEnabled doesn't create new TextView object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230621/textinputlayout-seterrorenabled-doesnt-create-new-textview-object)

[TextInputLayout.setError() leaves empty space after clearing the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242902/textinputlayout-seterror-leaves-empty-space-after-clearing-the-error)

[TextInputLayout not showing error message after clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912602/textinputlayout-not-showing-error-message-after-clearing)

[setError for TextInputLayout showing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397122/seterror-for-textinputlayout-showing-error)

[TextInputLayout error after enter value into edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808157/textinputlayout-error-after-enter-value-into-edittext)

[textinputlayout errorenabled and showing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233947/textinputlayout-errorenabled-and-showing-errors)

[textinputlayout errorenabled and showing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233947/textinputlayout-errorenabled-and-showing-errors)

[TextInputLayout's errorview is not removed when removing error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568952/textinputlayouts-errorview-is-not-removed-when-removing-error-message)

Gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Error Stacktrace,

```
Process: com.example.demo, PID: 31847
                                                                       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x1ec "res/color/secondary_text_material_dark.xml" a=1 r=0x1060120}
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:449)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:741)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:674)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:602)
                                                                           at com.example.demo.DemoActivity.canLogin(DemoActivity.java:163)
                                                                           at com.example.demo.DemoActivity.access$000(DemoActivity.java:24)
                                                                           at com.example.demo.DemoActivity$1.onClick(DemoActivity.java:54)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

Here is the XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="UserName"
        android:theme="@style/txtIptLayout"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tilUsername"
       app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
       >
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
         style="@style/txtEditTxtLayout"
         app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
         android:id="@+id/etUserName"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:inputType="text"

         />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:theme="@style/txtIptLayout"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_widget_icon_txtiptlayout"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
       app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
           style="@style/txtEditTxtLayout"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"


            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is what I am applying and this is where exactly the error is thrown,

```
tilPassword.setError("Password required");
                tilPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Just FYI, `TextInputLayout`'s error text isn't an "error tooltip that hovers over the text box". It appears underneath the `EditText`. An `EditText`'s error is a tooltip, though.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok it also doesn't appear underneath. it does not display instead that error is thrown. So can it be rectified ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  tilPassword.getEditText().setError("Password required");
  tilPassword..setErrorEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how but removing the theme attribute in XML `android:theme="@style/txtIptLayout"` worked. The assumption would be that overriding the theme from XML will override the theme for the tooltip and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well this happens, when you try to override the theme from XML, it will override the default functionalities as well. i have faced similar issue where i was creating a style parenting `TextAppearance.AppCompat`.

Replacing it with `Theme.AppCompat` resolved my issue.